# Magento date text: where does it come from and how can I change it?

Tags: magento

With the knowledge I've learned here from my recent Magento upgrade and ensuing fixing, **please help me with one of my biggest UI gripes: the date**. It is stupid:

[image]

I hacked the core file `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php` and changed '100px' to '165px', which prevents the date from wrapping. I'd really love to change the date from 'M n, Y g:i:s A' to something like Gmail uses 'g:i:s a' if today or 'M n, ga' if not today. I'd add in the year if the year of the date to be displayed wasn't the current year.

I saw [Overriding Magento Admin Controller, for Beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849338), which might be enough for me to override `_prepareColumns()` in the core file, but I'd really like to find out how to change that date! BTW, I grepped the whole install and no part of that date format string shows up.

---

**Update:** found that the date string format is set in `lib/Zend/Locale/Data/root.xml` and may be overridden if your locale is something other than en_us, whose file is empty. To expound upon the first part of R.S's answer, the date "format" is not php `date()` style, which I tried and got quite strange results. Perusing the Locale XML files, I made a few experiments, which are here:

```
    $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
        'index' => 'created_at',
        'type' => 'datetime',
        'format' => 'MMM d, h:mm a',  // Feb 18, 1:57 PM
        //'format' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_MEDIUM), 
        //'format' => 'MMM d, y G',
        'width' => '165px', // CKCK: edited to fix date field width was 100px
    ));
```

Working on making a custom module to override the block renderer. Part 2 of R.S's code as shown isn't working, but his links give me a recipe. Will update again with results.

---

**Update:**
I tried ([and failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948525/)) to override the Adminhtml block sales order grid (`absog`). Another module, EM_DeleteOrder was already overriding `absog`. I searched for a replacement module that didn't override `absog` and found an extension with great powers with respect to the sales grid: [MageWorx Enhanced Orders](http://www.mageworx.com/extended-orders-magento-extension.html). So I installed that and am hacking their source for the date format I want! I'm happy and done, no more updates to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$this->addColumn('created_at', array(
     'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
     'index' => 'created_at',
     'type' => 'datetime', 
     'format'    => 'MMM d, h:mm a',
     'width' => '165px',
));
```

You could also  use `renderer`

```
$this->addColumn('created_at', array(
     'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
     'index' => 'created_at',
      //'type' => 'datetime', //remove
      'renderer' = new MageIgniter_FormatDate_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Data()
      'width' => '165px',
));
```

Then create

```
class MageIgniter_FormatDate_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Data extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Action
{
  public function render(Varien_Object $row)
   {
     return $this->_getValue($row);
   }

   public function _getValue(Varien_Object $row)
   {
     $val = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());  // row value
     // need to format $val

     return $val;

   } 
}
```

See

- [Magento Customer Grid - Mask Email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691482/magento-customer-grid-mask-email-address)
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/192232/#t420795

Comment: Your exact code crashes the sales order grid, however, you've got me on the correct path, so marked `accepted`. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to make the change to core file (as I updated above) but am stuck trying to make adminhtml module. Please check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948525 ? Thanks!